# Wrong input behavior with 2 input languages (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS)

Tags: ibus, input-language

I installed a fresh version of ubuntu, with us and hungarian input added.

I use the hu keyboard for messaging/browsing and the standard US layout for coding. Using the US layout, when I press Z it inputs Z as expected, but when i press CTRL + Z it gets CTRL + Y. What causes this strange behavior?

This issue is IDE independent. I get this bug with IDEA and VSCODE too.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, is your keyboard a physical Hungarian layout? Which keyboard is the main setting of `sudo dpkg-reconfigure Keyboard-layout` ?

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka Yes. My physical keyboard layout is Hungarian. The keyboard-layout package is not installed, I went with the minimal ubuntu install.

Comment: @user3616048, I got it. `sudo apt install language-pack-hu` and open and configure Settings > Language & Region and etc. could add your necessary packages. I believe Hungarian keyboard is almost German, Z and Y are replaced from US layout. By the way, Dvorak layout offer QWERTY shortcuts on Mac OS X, if I remember correctly. You can remember your Ctrl+Z as it.